# Matlab - How to concatenate structures whilst maintaining time allignment?

Tags: matlab, struct, concatenation

I currently import data into a mat file, the data within this mat file is later imported into a structure after some operations have been completed to organise it.

Each field (data variable) within the structure has 2 double arrays of matching length (data & time) due to the differing sampling rates between variables.

One of the requirements here is that the data maintains its time allignment, however the time array for each variable always starts from 0 in all new files/structures, meaning that when a common variable name is found and concatenation of the arrays is required, the time array for the variable being concatenated must be altered to begin from the last value in the first time array (maybe by simply adding the last value to the first?).

In the event that the second structure has a variable name that the first does not, the time array for that variable should be adjusted in a similar way, maybe by taking the last value of time in other variable array from structure that we are concatenating to? Not sure about how to handle this as due to variables having varying sampling rates, they do not all end with the same value (can vary by 0.1 - 1 seconds)

I want to understand if it is possible to join multiple of these files together. The data & time arrays are what should be concatenated, so that we end up with one final structure of the same format.

Open to suggestions of other ways to handle this, concatenating these structres seems like a cumbersome way of going about it but I cannot see another way while maintaining the data format.

Comment: It is unclear what you need. Yes, you can concatenate them, you can modify the time of one so it comes after the other. There are possibly many other ways to combine the data. We don’t know what the data is or what you want to do with it, it, so don’t know what makes sense. Also, this is not about programming. Maybe ask over at [stats.se]?

Comment: Please Iceberg_Slim consider sharing the MATLAB code you need to fix or have it fixed by readers of your question. When a for instance byke owner needs a byke fixed, usually the 1st thing a do is to bring the faulty byke to the mechanic. Thanks for your understanding